# Does AWS ApiGateway Socket Splits Messages at 4 KB?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, webrtc, aws-api-gateway, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to implement WebRTC Signalling Server using AWS ApiGateway with javascript in order to connect 2 clients (Client A - Web Browser; Client B - Unreal Engine's PixelStreaming Plugin).

(Note: For this implementation I'm not using the signalling sever implementation provided by Unreal, but I'm creating a replacement implementation using AWS ApiGateway)

At first I connect successfully both clients to the Api Gateway WebSocket sever and setup the required configuration.

Then I'm generating the WebRTC "offer" from the browser (Client A) and send it using method [ApiGatewayManagementApiClient::PostToConnectionCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-apigatewaymanagementapi/index.html) (JS AWS SDK v3) via Lambda to the receiver's ConnectionID (Client B). I expect when the receiver (Client B) get the offer to generate an "answer". Instead of an answer from Client B I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to parse SS message ...<message-chunk>...
```

In the logs I get this error 2 times but with different chunks of my offer (first beginning of the JSON and second somewhere in the middle). This lead me to believe that the message got split, so I tried removing parts of the JSON (shorten it) until I stop getting the error. Doing this I found that this error disappears when the exact length of the JSON message is 4096 chars (4 KB). When I send event one byte over this I get the error (2 times).

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html) they have a maximum frame size of 32 KB. My full message is around 7 KB, so I expect that it is going to be sent at once. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case my message is split to 4 KB mark.

I have working implementation of the exact same case in NodeJS and building a custom server with the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) library. Inside this implementation everything is working correctly (my 7 KB offer get delivered in once piece and I receive answer and the connection is initiated without errors). I send "offer" and then receive "answer" back.

I've used [wscat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat) to connect to both servers (the NodeJS and the ApiGateway) assuming the role of Client B and I got both "offers". Then I compared them
and they are exactly the same. (In wscat the message doesn't look to be split, but I assume that they concat the chunks before showing it.)

Based on that I can assert that I'm configuring the clients properly and that the "offer" is good to receive "answer". The only difference is that if I send the offer from the NodeJS I receive answer and all works, but if I send exactly the same offer from AWS ApiGateway I got error that the data cannot be parsed (because it is split in 4 KB chunks).

I have spent 3 days trying to resolve this issue and I'm certain that everything I send and the way I send it is correct. So I come to conclusion that I for some reason hit some limit in AWS API Gateway or Lambda (I saw that Lambda has [4 KB limit on environment variables](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-environment-variable-size/), but I'm not using them so it should not be related) which causes my message to be split in parts. This causes the Unreal's Pixel Streaming Plugin to try deserialize the JSON in chunks instead of the whole JSON message at once and this results in 2 errors that the data cannot be parsed.

I cannot change the code of the client to first wait all the chunks to arrive and then process it. I have to use it "as is". (It is a plugin and it is written in C++)

I also tried to relay the API API Gateway Socket Message via NodeJS client and then to create a NodeJS Web Socket server connect the Unreal Engine Plugin to my NodeJS server and forward the message via it to the Unreal Engine Plugin. (AWS -> NodeJS Client -> NodeJS Server -> Unreal instead of AWS -> Unreal). This variant is working correctly without problem and I receive answer. The problem is that I introduce an additional NodeJS client and Server which beats the purpose of using API Gateway at first place...

So my question is: Is is possible that AWS API Gateway is splitting my  message in 4KB chunks (or Lambda does it) and if it is so is it possible to somehow increase this limit so I receive the whole message at once instead?

I can provide code in case it is needed, but I don't think the problem is related to the concrete implementation.